# rosbag record pointcloud2 and tf data best practice?

Tags: rosbag, transform, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the best way to record pointcloud2 data? I tried rosbag record but the bag file becomes too large(2G) only for about 30 seconds. I tried -j to compress, but it cannot work with infinite buffer size(-b 0).

I tried:
rosbag record -b 0 -O test.bag /tf /camera/rgb/points
and
rosbag record -b 0 -O test.bag -j /tf /camera/rgb/points

But both will exhaust all physical memory and throw a std::bad_alloc() exception then quit, so I have to limit the record to at most 80 seconds.
Any option to drop down the frame rate or compress the pointcloud2 data into binary compressed .pcd files, but still maintain corresponding /tf data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29871/rosbag-record-pointcloud2-and-tf-data-best-practice?/) by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 391 on 2012-03-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't need all of this data, you can use the [topic tools](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools) to drop or throttle messages, or the rostopic --filter to get rid of some messages.

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2012-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1551/k-chen/) on 2012-03-16**:
Thanks! That's what I am looking for.